# How to edit PATH in order to change path of a directory?

Tags: 14.04, android

I want to add ANDROID_HOME into my path.
I added following lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android/sdk/
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I want to edit `ANDROID_HOME` and set it to export `ANDROID_HOME=~/android/sdk` instead.How to do it? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add it to the path ...

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android/sdk/
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

If you want to replace tools and platform-tools by it ...

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android/sdk/
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME
```

In both versions it is added at the end of your $PATH. I assume the / missing in the last part of your question is a typo.

You need to add that to `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` if you do not care about other shells than bash).

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind. The problem is, ANDROID_HOME and PATH variables remove once I logout :( Is there any way that I have them permanently? Thanks. (I check by `printenv` command)

Comment: okay, I just added to my .bashrc file and problem solved. However, when I enter `adb kill-server` I'm getting "No such file or directory" message but by entering "ls -a /home/hesam/android/sdk/platform-tools/" command, `adb` is there. Do you have what is the problem?

Comment: okay, I just found the solusion there http://stackoverflow.com/a/26751401/513413

Comment: I was about to post that :D Well done! :)